# how to get total elapsed time in timeseries pandas dataframe for each group?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I want to calculate elapsed time in min for each group in my dataframe.
for example, I have following data frame, i want to calculate total elapsed time for each group "foo" and "bar".

```py
data = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "name": ["foo", "foo", "foo", "bar", "bar", "bar"],
        "time": [
            pd.to_datetime("2021-06-01 00:00:00"),
            pd.to_datetime("2021-06-01 00:15:00"),
            pd.to_datetime("2021-06-01 00:30:00"),
            pd.to_datetime("2021-06-01 00:00:00"),
            pd.to_datetime("2021-06-01 01:00:00"),
            pd.to_datetime("2021-06-01 01:30:00"),
        ],
    }
)
```

expected outout

```
 name                time  elapsed_min
0  foo 2021-06-01 00:00:00            0
1  foo 2021-06-01 00:15:00           15
2  foo 2021-06-01 00:30:00           30
3  bar 2021-06-01 00:00:00            0
4  bar 2021-06-01 01:00:00           60
5  bar 2021-06-01 01:30:00           90
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do groupby then transform to get the min of each group

```py
data['elapsed_min'] = (data['time'].sub(data.groupby('name')['time'].transform(min))
                       .dt.total_seconds().div(60))
```

```
print(out)

  name                time  elapsed_min
0  foo 2021-06-01 00:00:00          0.0
1  foo 2021-06-01 00:15:00         15.0
2  foo 2021-06-01 00:30:00         30.0
3  bar 2021-06-01 00:00:00          0.0
4  bar 2021-06-01 01:00:00         60.0
5  bar 2021-06-01 01:30:00         90.0
```

Comment: One quick question, is the order of values of elapsed time returns same as the name and time column?

Comment: @MananGajjar Yes, no operation affects the order.